# Trying to spot the syntax error

Tags: c#, sql

Getting this error when attempting to update user info in my code...

> ErrorSystem.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error in
>   UPDATE statement.   at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
>   hr)   at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
>   dbParams, Object& executeResult)   at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&
>   executeResult)   at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, Object& executeResult)   at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)   at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()   at
>   clsDataLayer.UpdateUser(String userName, String favProgram, String
>   City, String leastFav, String State, DateTime Date, Int32 userID1) in
>   c:\Users\John Vinson\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\WebSites\ProgramAnonymous\App_Code\clsDataLayer.cs:line 56   at
>   useraccount_details.updateinfo_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\John Vinson\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\WebSites\ProgramAnonymous\useraccount_details.aspx.cs:line 57

and here is the code...

```
public void UpdateUser(string userName, string favProgram, string City, string leastFav,
        string State, DateTime Date, int userID1)
    {
        dbConnection.Open();

        string sqlStmt = "UPDATE users SET userName = @username1, " +
            "favProgram = @favprogram1, " +
            "city = @city1, " +
            "state = @state1, " +
            "leastFavProgram = @leastfavprogram, " +
            "dateComplete = @datecomplete, " +
            "WHERE (users.userID = @id)";

        OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(sqlStmt, dbConnection);

        OleDbParameter param = new OleDbParameter("@username1", userName);
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@favprogram1", favProgram));
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@city1", City));
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@state1", State));
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@leastfavprogram", leastFav));
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@datecomplete", Date));
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@id", userID1));

        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        dbConnection.Close();

    }
```

Comment: You have a comma before the `WHERE`.  I vote to close these as simply typos.

Answer (score 1):

In order to *avoid* such pesky syntax errors, do not *build* (concatenate) queries from chunks, use *verbatim* strings to put query as a *single*, *readable* string:

```
    string sqlStmt = 
      @"UPDATE users
           SET userName = @username1,
               favProgram = @favprogram1,
               city = @city1,
               leastFavProgram = @leastfavprogram,
               dateComplete = @datecomplete -- <- no comma ',' should be here
         WHERE (users.userID = @id)";
```

There's a simple developing procedure: open SQL editor, write a correct query then put it (copy + paste) into `@""`